# SQL Server 2008 Resource Governor

Tags: sql-server-2008

What does the following function doing ?

I am trying to create Resource Governor in SQL 2008 for A particular Host_name

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnHostClassifier()
RETURNS sysname
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   BEGIN
       RETURN  host_name()
   END
GO
```

Comment: Is your question really just "what is the function doing"? It returns the result of the system `host_name` function which is described here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178598.aspx What aspect do you need clarified?

Answer (score 2):

the host_name function returns the workstation name.  The sql you have creates a UDF that does that.

You can read up on it more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178598.aspx).

If you are trying to work with the Resource Governor, I'd say you're looking in the wrong spot.  Start by doing some reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx).

Comment: Thanks all, I am in right direction want to put a governor on WFE from application connects to SQL and RG is working as expected.